# Adding external widget to django-filters

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-filter

I want to add a nice selector for the users. I use django-filter and wants to add a library django-selector2. I have something like this, I think it does not work as it should - it appears normal selector.

```
from django_select2 import *

class UserChoices(AutoModelSelect2Field):
    queryset = User.objects
    search_fields = ['word__icontains', ]


class Filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    user = UserChoices(widget=AutoHeavySelect2Widget())
    date_from = django_filters.DateFilter(widget=DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))
    date_to = django_filters.DateFilter(widget=DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'}))

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        form = MyForm
        fields = ['user', 'date_from', 'date_to']
```

My view:

```
class Dashboard(TableFilterView):
    model = MyModel
    table_class = TableOfUsers
    template_name = "lists.html"
    context_object_name = 'obj'
    filterset_class = Filter

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Dashboard, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        f = MyForm()
        context['f'] = f
        return context
```

In the template I have:

```
{% load django_select2_tags %}
{% import_django_select2_js %}
{% import_django_select2_css %}
{% import_django_select2_js_css light=1 %}
```